# PHP Multi process GONE?

Tags: php, linux

I have a script that when I execute, the site becomes unresponsive, while other sites on the same server are working well!

The script is nothing more than downloading a file from remote server and some few MySQL calls (5 maybe).

How can this script be affecting the entire site?

Comment: There could be dozens of answers to that question. Be more specific: show some code maybe.

Comment: You query is probably choking database, which every script on site use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any specifics, my best guess is session locking.

When you access your site, your session file gets locked. All consecutive request to the same site with the same session id will have to wait till this one finishes.

If you want to release this lock, use `session_write_close()`.